# check any one of a word of a list is present in a string (without space) using excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to check if in a given cell exists any one word from a list

Example :
[image]

I have tested using all options in https://www.exceldemy.com/return-value-if-cells-contain-certain-text-from-a-list/
However, none of them working since my string doesnt have a space

Comment: Can you include your formula/vba-code for debugging? Otherwise it seems as though you asking for free code which would be off-topic on SO. It would also help if you can add sample data in markdown-format (so people won't have to write their own).

Comment: What's wrong with free code @JvdV? It's an easy problem with an easy  solution. Besides we rise by helping others.

Comment: @JohnDaPleaserofWimmin, some other websites might be accepting these questions indeed but SO encourages a different approach. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. And also, see [how much effort is required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) from someone who asked a question. I do agree that depending on the topic I also sometimes feel too enthused in answering a question that is lacking all the previous mentioned required effort. And to be honest, in this case a simple formula would suffice if OP searches on SO's dup's.

Comment: @JohnDaPleaserofWimmin it's fine, if you are willing to just do the job for others, but in general SO is for people trying to get better at programming. By throwing snippets at them, before they have even tried, they won't be.

Comment: + If ppl arent told that the way they aks questions is unwellcome at SO, they may wonder why nobody answers

Comment: @FloLie Sometimes you've gotta give a person a hand, especially those new to programming. I don't expect my kids to understand multiplication by telling them "just go do it and come back to me with what you got". No, I go through examples with them, and before long they're multiplication wizards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it in VBA for you:

```
Dim SearchStrings As Range
Dim FindRange As Range
'This is the range of cells to check
    For Each SearchStrings In Range("A1:A6")
    'This is the range of cells to compare
        For Each FindRange In Range("G1:G3")
        
            If InStr(SearchStrings.Value, FindRange.Value) Then
               'Do whatever it is you want to do with the match result here
               'I've just done a Debug.Print for demonstration.
                Debug.Print (SearchStrings(, 1).Value)
            End If
            Next FindRange
        Next SearchStrings
```